# How to stop Knowledge being enabled in a Scratch Org?

Tags: salesforcedx

The following is the Scratch Org definition I'm using:

```
{
    "orgName": "Test Company",
    "edition": "Enterprise",
    "features": ["API", "AuthorApex", "ContactsToMultipleAccounts", "DebugApex"],
    "settings": {
        "orgPreferenceSettings": {
            "s1DesktopEnabled": true
        },
        "knowledgeSettings": {
            "enableKnowledge": false
        }
    }
}
```

When I use this definition file I get the following error message:

> === Component Failures [1]
>   Error  shape/settings/Knowledge.settings  Knowledge  Once enabled, Salesforce Knowledge can't be disabled.
>   ERROR:  Failed to deploy settings to scratch org.

Is there a particular feature listed there that is resulting in Knowledge being enabled?

Comment: I know, this is a while back, but did you find any solution for disabling Knowledge in Enterprise edition scratch orgs?